# What is special about children of Athena?

Tags: athena

Taking an example from Rick Riordan's Greek Mythology series, Annabeth herself complained for not being able to do anything as a daughter of Athena. All other children, even minor gods seem to have way more power and strength than Athena's children.

Besides strategy/war, intelligence and planning, what other powers do these children have? How could they possibly compare to other demigods that can fly, or summon hurricanes? Even a benevolent goddess like Aphrodite has kids that can "charmspeak" or will others to do things just from voice.

Comment: Rick Riordan's books are based on Greek Mythology sort of like how the Marvel THOR movies are based on Norse mythology. They're a fun intro to the world for new audiences, but if anything doesn't make sense the answer is usually "because he made it up."

Answer (score 4):

In Greek mythology, Athena swore herself to virginity, she had no children born from her. According to some localized myths, she adopted a single child, born from Gaia called [Erichthonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erichthonius_of_Athens).

Rick Riordan's Annabeth has no Ancient Greek mythological basis. Etymologically, Annabeth is not even a Greek name. It's a combination of "Anna" & "Elisabeth", both Hebrew in origin.

Comment: For those who have not read the series, Riordan had her conceive children *mentally* and bear them from her head, as she was born from Zeus.  So she was still a virgin in his books.  That whole shebang was his invention, too.